# dataframe apply function error when calling function from external py file

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter, apply

dataframe apply function operates differently when I use functions from external `.py` file as arguments in the apply function.

In jupyter notebook, my code is working well when I define function in the same `.ipynb` file. However, when I import a function from `.py` file, I get errors like `("name 'pd' is not defined", 'occurred at index 0')`.

```
import pandas as pd
import ind_assign as ind
def ffi48(x):
    if (3000<=x['sic'] <= 4000):
        ffi48 = 1
    if (4000<x['sic'] <= 5000):
        ffi48 = 2
    return pd.Series({'sic':x['sic'], 'ffi48': ffi48})


d = {'sic': [3725, 4920]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.apply(ffi48, axis=1) 
or
df.apply(ind.ffi48, axis=1)
```

`df.apply(ffi48, axis=1)` works well. However, when I make `ind_assign.py` file with `ffi48` function and call like `df.apply(ind.ffi48, axis=1)`, I got errors such as
`("name 'pd' is not defined", 'occurred at index 0')`.

Comment: When you call `df.apply(ind.ffi48, axis=1)`, Python is ignoring everything outside the function, so your `import pandas as pd` in ind.py is being ignored. Try importing pandas in the file where you are calling ind.py.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I import pandas but still have the error.

Answer (score 0):

I just recreated your error. You need to `import pandas as pd` in the `ind_assign.py` file as suggested, then save `ind_assign.py`, but then you also need **to restart your kernel** within the notebook. After restarting the kernel, it works as expected.

https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469240-Jupyter-IPython-After-editing-a-module-changes-are-not-effective-without-kernel-restart?mobile_site=true